# Decode a Zend Guard encoded file with Zend Studio

Tags: php, decode, zend-studio, zend-guard

So I have a fairly large system which we have encoded with Zend Guard. As this pretty badly messes up any SVN control, its a bit of a pain to deploy / make changes.

Does anyone know if its possible to use the Zend Studio FTP editing to decode and edit files that have been encoded? When I open them it says

```
The file filepath/filename.php was encoded by Zend Guard. Would you like to open it anyway?
```

If you click yes, it just opens the raw encoded file. I have both Zend Guard / Studio installed on my system, and in preferences both apps point to the other so they know they are installed. Seems a bit of a pain if it wont do this.

I can browse the files in Zend Guard and then open in Zend Studio, but this will only let me edit files in the output location, which is not on the live server

FYI I am using Zend Studio 5.5.1 (not latest).

**NOTE:** I want to be able to edit encoded files from a live FTP via Zend Studio, not what is mentioned here - http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/opening_and_editing_zend_guard_projects_in_neon.htm which is already mentioned above

Comment: Have you tried to actually decode the file before opening it?

Comment: Are you able to set the editor your SVN client launches?

Comment: @hakre my point is surely if I try and open an encoded file in Zend Studio, surely it should decode it automatically?

Comment: @Horse: Should it? I mean I can understand you want that Zend studio to do, but does it actually support that? Is it a feature? Or is your question if it is a feature or not?

Comment: @hakre yeah just want to know if its possible or not? the new live server is giving me problems, and would be handy to be able to edit live to debug / troubleshoot instead of trying something, re-encode the whole project, then ftp the files up that changed, rinse + repeat

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? :[Opening and Editing Zend Guard Projects in Zend Studio](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/opening_and_editing_zend_guard_projects_in_neon.htm)

Comment: Nope sorry. As in OP, 2nd from last sentence, I can already do that. I want to edit them live from the new server, not the copies I have locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for in NOT a feature of Zend Studio nor would it ever be one.  Files are encoded By Zend Guard for security reasons.  If Zend just allowed them to be unencoded from within Studio that would render Guard pretty much ineffective for the ISV's that use it.

You should work with the original source files before they are run through Guard and encode before transferring to the server.  If you do not have the original source files then you should probably be contacting the party that does ....

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I would think that if I had both guard and studio installed, and the license files then decoding should not be a problem. As you say I will have to do it via the original source, just a pain as having issues with the code on the live server and not our dev environment